# Is there any way to convert text to wav file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to convert a text file to a .wav file with these properties:

Audio sampling rate: 8 kHz,
Audio sample size: 16 Bit,
Channel: Mono,
Bit rate: 128kbps

Is there any way to do it in python directly? I searched on google and found that we can convert text to mp3 and then from mp3 to .wav but I would require those properties to be included as well

Comment: How do you want to do this conversion? For example, the text file contains words and you want to convert it into spoken voice?

Comment: No Enzo, The file contains words and I just want a .wav file of it with the above properties. When I open that .wav file then it should speak the words of that text file. Please let me know If you are able to understand my requirement.

Comment: Generally speaking, converting between audio formats is easy. Doing text to speech in the first place is *very hard*. So focus on the hard part first, get that solved, then deal with the specific requirements of the output format at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a text-to-speech library or service that receives a text as input and generates an audio file with some voice.

There are several options here, one of them is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-text-speech-python/ , another one that I recommend is IBM Cloud Watson's https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home.

Of course, some will perform better than others, according to the technology used, and language of choice, because each language has its own accent. Cloud-based ones like IBM's will let you play a little, but if you need to generate lots of audio files, you'll have to pay to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Shikida. I was able to find the articles to convert text to speech but how to set those properties on the . WAV file which will be generated.

Comment: @SujitSingh: How you control the output format is likely to be very specific to each library. So pick one, read its documentation, and see where that gets you. If you can't configure it to exactly match your requirements, consider letting it produce some audio output in whatever format it wants and doing the conversion into your specific format as a second step.

Comment: Thanks much Blckknght. Yes, I am trying that side by side. I hope I can achieve what I want. :)